# How to edit children objects in ue5 bp

Tags: unreal-engine5, blueprint

I have a blueprint called Bp_Checkpoint and its children can be shown here:

[image: Tree]

I would like to change the text of the Text Render object on game start but I don't know how to get it since it is farther down in the tree.

[image: What I want]

I think this is descriptive enough but if not let me know.

Comment: Those are not "children" they are "components". Try [this node](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Actor/GetComponentsByClass/).

Comment: yeah but if they are under each other in the treeview wouldn't that imply that the components are children?

Comment: The term you search for in this context are "components". There are child actors, child components, child widgets, etc. everything can be a child. These are components to the actor and not children. The actor has a root component and every child to that are the root components "children". You came here to ask a question about "child objects", and I just corrected your terminology. Not only will this help you in the future when asking questions but especially when using a search engine.